# Exp-resso Store : Trade and web customers

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

First post here, have read the faq etc and actually found a similar question, but rules say I should not tag a question onto an answer.

( [Trade prices in exp:resso Store](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/678/trade-prices-in-expresso-store) )

Scenario : Website currently only sells to trade. Website displays all info apart from price to visitors. Trade clients have a manually assigned login and prices are then displayed. Ordering is carried out off site.

Client would like to offer online ordering to existing Trade customers, and potentially general web customers.

Would it be possible to set up a Trade Store field and a Customer Store field within the channel and then use conditionals to display within the templates? There will obviously be some duplication of entry in the channel entry, but this appears to me to be the easiest work around.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the linked post. You can only assign one Store field per entry so you would either need to do

> If your products are fairly simple and wont have modifiers effecting the price you can create the different price levels as modifiers per product then use a conditional in your template to preselect the proper modifier in a hidden field. The only downside to this is that the product modifier names would need to be the same so the in   template conditionals worked without any problems.
>
> The second option would be to create 2 channels for your products. Lets call the first channel "product_details" which would house all of your details about the product but would not contain a Store fieldtype. In the second channel lets call it "product_prices" you would want to create 3 fields a Store fieldtype, Playa, and a dropdown or select field that would allow you select which member group the entry would apply to. Then in your template you would list the items on the site using the product_details channel and would then need to have the playa field search for the related entries where you dropdown or select had a value of the currently logged in member.

If you wanted to have different prices per member group. IF you are just wanting to only show the prices to people that are logged in as trade members you can do something along the line of:

```
{if member_group == X}{price}{/if}
```

Where "X" is the member group id of the trade group. If you do not want to sell to normal visitors you could do something along the lines of

```
{if logged_in}{price}{if:else}Log into see the price{/if}
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, that seems fairly logical.

Random thought : would setting up a P&T Matrix for Trade customers work and not screw with potential Store customers?

Comment: It shouldn't cause any problems.